# android ImageButton gets gray background

Tags: android, background, imagebutton

i have a Button with a nice background selector. fine. in stead of text in the button, i want an image. i have tried just changing it to an ImageButton with a src attribute. when i do this, it looks like a gray background is overlaid behind my selector, behind the src image.

when i change back to a regular Button, the problem goes away. what i want is just my background selector, plus the src image (in stead of the button text).

any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ImageButton should have android:background set.

```
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/ibArrow"
    android:layout_width="35px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundstate" />
```

And backgroundstate:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
   </selector>
```

Comment: I had the same issue with image button.. that works very well :)

Comment: and yes close the selector node.

Answer (score 2):

What @kdumitru said, but with the correct XML stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you might not be referencing the image correctly in R.drawable  maybe you need to place image in drawable?  ImageView does work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing? Hard to tell exactly what you're saying, but it sounds like your src image may not have a proper alpha channel. Is it a PNG with transparency? Make sure your src image is a properly saved, transparent PNG image.

Comment: here's an example of one of the images i tried: http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/actions/gtk-media-forward-ltr.png. to work around this, i used a regular button, removed the text, reference the image via android:drawableTop, then squashed the button by manually setting the height. the method shows the image and background correctly. based on this, my assumption is that the image is correct.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what the issue looks like? Your transparency seems fine.