# setting ImageButton's background transparent with Theme.Light in android

Tags: java, android

**How to set the background color of an ImageButton 'transparent' ?**

The following piece of code works when I try it with default android theme, but with 'Theme.Light', I see a gray background.

```
ImageButton deleteBtn = new ImageButton( this );
deleteBtn.setImageResource( R.drawable.delete_big );
deleteBtn.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
```

(I need to dynamically create these buttons.. I have seen solutions which mention specifying @null background color using android's layout.xml files. How can I achieve the same thing programmatically ? Any help highly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: image with gray background here:]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174835/android-imagebutton-gets-gray-background/5891856#5891856 -- worked quite well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar to this and I used a transparent png 9patch. Then you can set it to the background with something like:

```
deleteBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.transparent_bground);
```

Edit: [here is a 9 patch you can use.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5724095/images/transparent_bground.9.png) Save it in one of your res/drawable folders.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is kind of answered, here's what went wrong.

Watch out for colors. `android.R.color.transparent` actually is an integer referencing a lookup table, and every time you set a color in Android in Java, it takes in an integer that represents the color.

Now, this is the tricky part: What's happening here is that it's setting the bg color to the lookup table index, which happens to translate to gray. If I remember right, `getResources().getColor(id)` is a function that can be called from a context or activity to get your correct color.